# Keeping EntityManager of Doctrine in a session variable

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, session-variables, entitymanager

I'm developing a web-application and I'm going to use docrine framework to manage,
concurrent requests and transactional queries (like inserting or updating head and rows records).

For web necessities I thought to split operations in different steps:
First step: I have a page that allows the user for inserting a HeadTable record and after that I send the information to the server, create a Entity and store it in a EntityManager with a persist function.

Second step: The user will edit and insert all the RowsTable records. When it's all done, like before, I send all the data to the server, create Entities and Associate them to the HeadTable record.

The final step: When the user confirm all he has done, I trigger the flush operation of the EntityManager and commit all to DataBase in a single atomic transaction.
To keep all this steps toghether I put the EntityManager in a session variable and I remove it after the flush operation.

All seems to be fine but i would like to know if it's the correct way to resolve the problem or if there's a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a reasonable thing to try.

I'd probably avoid storing the entitymanager across requests, however.  It's got a database connection to worry about, and will therefore probably break.

What you *can* do, however, is just store your entities in session.  detach() them from their entitymanager, and then merge() them back on the next request.